# mybatis : It's likely that neither a Result Type nor a Result Map was specified

Tags: mybatis

i use mybatis do some CRUD to mysql.

i meet an error : org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: A query was run and no Result Maps were found for the Mapped Statement 'com.huawei.it.iscp.scop.send.dao.IEspaceDao.findEspaceLogById'.  It's likely that neither a Result Type nor a Result Map was specified.

i check my mapper xml, i have resultType parameter in select tag.

i don't know,why mybatis still throw this error.

Comment: maybe because my bean's get set method for resultType is missing...

Comment: You need to add more details. At least show the mapping of the statement you have the problem with.

Answer (score 0):

In `select` statements MyBatis expects some data to return and it needs to know how exactly to map it.
So you have to add a `resultType` or `resultMap` tag into your mapping.

Here is an hypothetical example of mapping:

```
<resultMap id="espaceLogEntityResultMap" type="com.huawei.it.iscp.scop.send.dao.EspaceLogEntity">
        <result property="id" column="ID"/>
        <result property="entityField1" column="some_column1"/>
        <result property="entityField2" column="some_column2"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="findEspaceLogById" resultMap="espaceLogEntityResultMap">
    SELECT ID, some_column1, some_column2      
    FROM EspaceLogEntity 
    WHERE ID=#{id}
</select>
```

or

```
<select id="countEspaceLog" resultType="long">
    SELECT count(*)    
    FROM EspaceLogEntity
</select>
```